# Connection Timeout on Google Play

Tags: google-play-store, 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, asus-eee-pad-transformer

I have a brand new ASUS Transformer Prime tablet running ICS which I have been using for the first time over the last few days.

I can access the internet without issue using the email, Gmail, browser, YouTube apps, but not Google Play. When I try to use the Google Play Store app it shows a "loading..." message for a few minutes and then stops with a "No Connection" message.

Any ideas how I can fix this?

Answer (score 1):

I was on the verge of packing the tablet up and returning it to Amazon and thought I would try one last thing. I took the tablet to a friends house and tried it on their WIFI just to double check it was not my network. The table worked first time and I used Google Play to install a number of apps.

I then took the tablet back to my house and Google Play continued to work and I installed some more apps.

I have no idea what my router was blocking that prevented Google Play from working but it seems fine now. If the problem returns I know the issue is with my router now, not the tablet.

Comment: Note that the market in your device is actually an application trying to connect to a distant service in a certain why, while the internet simply loads web pages if a connection is found. I personally get the same issue you've described a lot so when it happens I just switch to G3 instead and it works. so it may just be an issue with the market app.

Answer (score 0):

I am also using a ASUS Transformer Prime tablet but the Play runs very well in that. I would suggest the following,

1. Restart the tablet.
2. Try to charge for atleast 8 hours

Also did u install the latest firmware that is being provided by ASUS, that firmware is a bug filled update. Do not update that. If you have updated it then it could be because of that.

Comment: What does charging have to do with this?

Comment: Sometime due to poor battery the tab is not able to connect properly to the Wifi or the 3G/4G data connection. (My own experience)

Comment: And it takes 8 hours to charge it up?

Comment: 8 hours is generic time that I wrote since that is the time duration one should charge when they take their device out of the box. So 8 hours completely saturates the battery.